# Trying to render on Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory, render, blender

I am trying to use colab to render my blender file.
But I got this error:

> Blender 3.1.0 (hash c77597cd0e15 built 2022-03-09 00:34:48) Read
> blend: /content/drive/MyDrive/blender/battary2.1.blend
>
> Error: Could not initialize streams, probably unsupported codec
> combination
>
> Blender quit

the code:

```
#Copy Blender back to Colab
!cp /content/drive/MyDrive/blender/blender-3.1.0-linux-x64.tar.xz /content/blender-3.1.0-linux-x64.tar.xz

#install Blender
!tar xf blender-3.1.0-linux-x64.tar.xz

#set the paths to your Blender Files
filename = '/content/drive/MyDrive/blender/battary2.1.blend'

#RenderSettings
!./blender-3.1.0-linux-x64/blender $filename -b -noaudio -E 'CYCLES' -o "/content/drive/MyDrive/GoogleColabTutorial/Renders/EeveeRender_" -s 5 -e 6 -a -F 'JPEG' -- --cycles-device CUDA
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I found that removing any space or dot in the file name could solve this problem. Thank You